# Exporting multiple divisions in html file to PDF using JSPDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf, html2canvas

I am working on a requirement where I need to export HTML file to PDF on button click. My html file is having multiple divisions and I have to export selected divisions to PDF after converting them to canvas-image. I am bit new to JsPDF and Html2canvas libraries, Below code is working fine for single division. Please suggest changes to this in order to handle multiple div export to PDF.

```
<button id="btn">Generate PDF</button>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/0.5.0-alpha2/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" >
 (function(){
     var 
      form = $('.test'),
      cache_width = form.width(),
      a4  =[ 595.28,  841.89];  // for a4 size paper width and height

     $('#create_pdf').on('click',function(){
      $('body').scrollTop(0);
      createPDF();
     });
     //create pdf
     function createPDF(){
      getCanvas().then(function(canvas){
       var 
       img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
       doc = new jsPDF({
               unit:'px', 
               format:'a4'
             });     
             doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);
             doc.save('techumber-html-to-pdf.pdf');
             form.width(cache_width);
      });
     }

     // create canvas object
     function getCanvas(){
      form.width((a4[0]*1.33333) -80).css('max-width','none');
      return html2canvas(form,{
          imageTimeout:2000,
          removeContainer:true
         }); 
     }

     }());
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

"test" is the class name of one div in my form but I am not able to use the below code for multiple divs